# jQuery("ul.sf-menu").superfish is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Receiving an error "jQuery("ul.sf-menu").superfish is not a function" during site load in Firefox, if I delete the superfish, it errors out upon the next snippet of javascript leading me to believe it's a jQuery reference error, which has been quadruple-checked and confirmed it's being loaded: http://yolokids.org.previewdns.com/?page_id=7

Here is the jquery being loaded fine in the header:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://yolokids.org.previewdns.com/wp-content/themes/theme1270/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js?ver=1.8.1'></script>
```

Here is the code referenced in the footer:

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
                // initialise plugins
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                        // main navigation init
                        jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish({
                            delay:       '<?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_delay'); ?>',      // one second delay on mouseout 
                            animation:   {opacity:'<?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_fade_in'); ?>',height:'<?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_slide_down'); ?>'}, // fade-in and slide-down animation 
                            speed:       '<?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_speed'); ?>',  // faster animation speed 
                            autoArrows:  <?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_arrows'); ?>,        // generation of arrow mark-up (for submenu) 
                            dropShadows: <?php echo get_option('my_framework_sf_dropshadows'); ?>    // drop shadows (for submenu)
                        });

                        // prettyphoto init
                        jQuery("#gallery .portfolio a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                            animationSpeed:'slow',
                            theme:'facebook',
                            slideshow:false,
                            autoplay_slideshow: false,
                            show_title: true,
                            overlay_gallery: false
                        });

                    });
              </script>

                <?php if( is_front_page() || is_home() ) { ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                          //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher
                            jQuery(document).bgStretcher({
                             images: ['<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/body-1.jpg'], imageWidth: 1920, imageHeight: 1200
                            });
                        });
                  </script>
               <?php } ?>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                      //  Initialize Backgound Stretcher
                        jQuery(document).bgStretcher({
                         images: ['<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/body-2.jpg'], imageWidth: 1920, imageHeight: 1200
                        });
                    });
               </script>
```

Basically the superfish, bgstretcher and pretty photo js references should all load correctly on the above URL but they continue to fail loading one by one starting with the suckerfish js. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The "superfish" plugin is probably not loaded: *where* are those extension functions defined?

Answer (score 4):

On line 202, you reload jQuery for your slider.  This effectively overwrites the $ and jQuery variables removing all additional plugins.

Comment: thank you! This was definitely on the right track to fixing the references.

Answer (score 2):

i changed your call of:

```
jQuery('ul.sf-menu').superfish()
```

to:

```
$('ul.sf-menu').superfish()
```

and it didn't throw the error for me.

Comment: thank you! This is along the right track. Getting to editing the references now which seem to be loading properly. Lots of clean-up!